# Can I upload iOS app with different account's certificate/provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

An app is developed for a client and we are looking on how to sign and upload it. I have enrolled to the developer program and told client to do the same, so both are individual accounts. I see iTunes Connect allows to add another user:

[image]

That allows client to add developer to the iTunes Connect. So can I upload an app signed with my provisioning profile, all the certificates to his iTunes Connect account?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no. In order to upload the app and make it under your client account, then your client should upload it. You can upload it under your account and later do app transfer to make it under your client account, but if you ask me, if your client has a developer account already, send him the project, explain him how to set its cert/prov in Xcode and upload the app (or ask him permission to do it for him). That way everything will be under his account to begin with.

Comment: If I upload it to mine and then transfer it, which one's certificates will be needed to update it?

Comment: Everything is being transferred including app id. That means that in order to submit an update, you will have to use your clients certificate. (Considering you've made the app transfer)

Comment: Hmm. What if I get him to create a certificate on his account, get him to download it and send it to me? Would I be able to use that certificate on my computer to sign it?

Comment: Yea that would work, you will need to make sure to get both certificate and private key (can be achieved by proper export of cert from keychain app) you will also have to add his account in your Xcode and download all his provision profiles. Basically you will "act" as him. In that case, skip the app transfer and do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, only company accounts can add users. Individual accounts — as the name suggests — can't.
Any individual account can be converted to a company account free of charge provided that you have a registered business name. It takes about a week. See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/).

If you have a company account, you can indeed add users and allow them to sign app on your behalf. These users will not use their personal signing assets, but those of the company account that grants them access.
Access is not given on iTunes Connect but on the developper website ([developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)).

Giving access on iTunes Connect allows to upload already signed builds and distribute them. So if you want someone to do all the work, you need to grant them access on both sides.

Comment: I have an individual account and I have already added another person through iTunes Connect "Users and Roles" option, just for testing. It works and he is able to browse it, like me. But my question is still the same, do provisioning profiles/certificates must match the account owner's? If I had access to client's iTunes Connect account, could I upload with my prov profiles/certificates?

Comment: As I said, adding users to iTunes Connect will allow them to browse and update details of your apps but it will not allow them to sign apps. In other words, even if you give them the source of you app, they will not be able to upload a build to iTunes Connect from it because they won't be able to sign this build.

Comment: But I have my own individual account, so I can sign the app with certificates generated on my account. Couldn't I upload it on his account?

Comment: No you can't, you can only distribute apps that you sign with your signing identity.

Comment: Thanks. If the client is not a company, he cannot create a company account, so what should be done?

Comment: If you're both individuals, there is no way to collaborate on an app. Maybe you could build the app yourself and have them sign it, bu I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Or you ask them for their account credentials... But this is a terrible last resort bad idea, you did't get it from me